# Does a Verpflichtungserklärung expire?

Tags: germany, study

My uncle gave me a Verpflichtungserklärung (declaration of commitment) for my student visa application. It was issued to him on 7th July 2018 with validity starting from 1st September 2018.

I didn't make it for the winter semester, but I hope to make the summer semester that starts in April. That means I will have to go for another visa interview in my country.

Can I still use the same Verpflichtungserklärung to apply for another visa or does it have an expiry date?

Answer (score 6):

The declaration is valid for six month starting with the date of issue. [Source: Federal Foreign Office](https://www.auswaertiges-amt.de/de/13-verpflichtungserklaerung/606492)

I can't find any official source for it, but I am pretty sure that the declaration can only be used for *one* visa application. Didn't you get the declaration in original from your uncle, which you then submitted when applying for the first visa? Or do you still have the original declaration?